cin command being entirely ignored
I'm very new to programming of any kind, so to practice, I'm trying to make a simple game where you select a dice (d4, d6, d8, etc.). Then a random number generator rolls that dice, and you have to guess the number within 3 guesses. The problem is I'm being stopped right at the start. There is an opening message that asks if you want to read the rules or begin the game, but for some reason, the program is just not caring about the very first input. It just prints the starting welcome message and Invalid. Try again. without any input. help?
(the code is kind of bare bones rn because I just started).
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  
  srand (time(NULL));

  // The variable section
  int open;

  //the opening bit
  std::cout << "Welcome to Dice Roller! For information on Dice Roller, type 1. To begin, type 2: ";
  std::cin >> open;

   if (open == 1) {
    std::cout << "Ok";
  } else if (open == 2) {
    std::cout << "Great!";
  } else {
    std::cout << "Invalid. Try again.";
  }
}


It isn’t an error in your program. Something is wrong with your runtime environment. How are you executing the program? (BTW, “open” is a Very Bad name for a variable.)

are you sure there's no input before this? Are you perhaps using input redirection? If std::cin >> open fails then no more input will be accepted until you call cin.clear/cin.ignore

I'm embarrassed to say I didn't think of that. You're gonna make fun of me, but I was just using codecademy's in-browser environment. I'm downloading Visual Studio Code now, thank you for the advice

Side note:  switch (open) { /*...*/};?

No one will make fun of you. It’s all part of the learning process. We all went through it.

For randomization in modern C++, use the new implementation. As for srand, that's C, not C++. You were probably thinking of ::std::srand if you wanna use the outdated methods.
